# Auto-layout not regular across different screen size

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am new to iOS platform but still been able to build my first app in the last 3 weeks. Coming from android, I was able to leverage of some of the knowledge I had to adapt quickly to swift and iOS but I struggle with auto-layout in the storyboard. I have not been able to get a flow that works.

I am currently using Xcode 11 and have tried to UIScrollView but to no uniformity. Whatever I arrange correctly on iPhone 11 deforms on iPhone 8 or lower.

I have watched different tutorials on youtube, lynda.com and pluralsight but to no avail.

What is the best possible way to use auto-layout across different screens like we have in android with constraint layout/relative layout?

[image]

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5758454-uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Tough to give answers to a question like yours. You show a layout side-by-side on different device sizes, but you don't say how you want the design to change when the size changes. Maybe if you show this exact layout side-by-side on two Android devices (with the same size difference as you are showing here), and we can see the "magic" layout and help you understand how to replicate it on iOS.

Comment: I want the views to be as they on the left. I have constrained them properly on the left but going to the device on the right doesnt show well

Comment: @Darotudeen - well, ok... but obviously, since the screens have much different heights, either the top or the bottom or parts of each will be cut-off unless the spacing / sizing is adjusted. In the image you posted, the spacing ***IS*** being adjusted. But, since you say it "deforms," show how you ***want*** it to look on the smaller screen.  We cannot guess what you want as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using anchor constrains programmatically. Setting border relative to different items will provide autolayout in all devices. If you post a screenshot of your needs , it might be easier to provide accurate answer. Also keep in mind that superview borders in iphone 8 and lower version differ from borders in higher version according to the top notches. You need to set your views relative to safe area of the superview.